# Copy from one sheet * by 2 and then paste

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that copies data from one workbook to another.  This aspect works fine.  I have a few cells which are causing me an issue as i need the value to come through as double its original value.

So basically one workbook has the radius and when it comes into the next workbook it needs to be the diameter, so i need to do a x2 somehow.  I have tried doing a few things with no luck, i have also looked on the web and there doesnt seem to be a clear cut answer.

My code is this: -

`OpenBook.Sheets("Input 2").Range("C39").Copy
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range(ItemCell & "36").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

WHich works great as a simple copy from one workbook to paste to another.  But i want to do something like this: -

`OpenBook.Sheets("Input 2").Range("C39").Copy
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range(ItemCell & "36").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues *2`

Any ideas?

I have seen this on the web `Operation:=xlMultiply` but dont understand how it works.  I also found a lot of sites and people sayings its impossible. I am hoping they are wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the clipboard and transfer the value, multiplying by 2:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range(ItemCell & "36").Value = OpenBook.Sheets("Input 2").Range("C39").Value * 2
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks Ben. I tried something very similar to that but when it did come through all the formatting changed, how is it that that maintains the formatting please?

Comment: Would this also speed everything up?

Comment: If you need to transfer formatting, then use the clipboard (but you were pasting values in the original question so I'm not sure what the requirement is exactly). This approach does not change the format of the target cell at all, and yes this is better/faster then using copy/pastespecial.

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you, no i didnt want to transfer the formatting.  When i tried that way previously it transferred the formatting and messed up the receiving sheet.  i guess the `.value` brings through just the value.  Thank you very much i will update all my code now to this way! (I have been trying to suss this out for about 4 hours with web surfing, should have asked on here 3 hours ago). Very happy thank you again Ben!